# Scrollview not working inside Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-scrollview

My Dialog's layout is a Scrollview and have some Textviews and some EditText but when I open the soft keyboard to enter something in EditText than keyboard is overlapping my view and it is not scrolling.

I have tried many solutions like setting fillViewPort to true and making LinearLayout to Scrollview's child but nothing is working for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

My XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_xsmall">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                android:id="@+id/spa_section"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/border_transparent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/spa"
                    android:text="@string/spa"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/transparent_grey"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/spa_qty"
                    android:hint="@string/no_of_spa"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ellipsize="start"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spa"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spa"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                android:id="@+id/restro_section"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/border_transparent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spa_section"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xsmall">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/restro"
                    android:text="@string/restro"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/transparent_grey"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/restro_qty"
                    android:hint="@string/no_of_restro"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ellipsize="start"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/restro"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/restro"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                android:id="@+id/bar_section"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/border_transparent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                android:layout_below="@+id/restro_section"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xsmall">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/bar"
                    android:text="@string/bar"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/transparent_grey"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/bar_qty"
                    android:hint="@string/no_of_bar"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ellipsize="start"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bar"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bar"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                android:id="@+id/conference_room_section"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/border_transparent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bar_section"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xsmall">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/conference_room"
                    android:text="@string/conference"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/transparent_grey"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/conference_room_qty"
                    android:hint="@string/conference_rooms"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ellipsize="start"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/conference_room"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/conference_room"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/border_transparent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                android:layout_below="@+id/conference_room_section"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xsmall">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/banquet"
                    android:text="@string/banquet"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/transparent_grey"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
                    android:id="@+id/banquet_qty"
                    android:hint="@string/banquet_halls"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ellipsize="start"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/banquet"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/banquet"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/options"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ok"
                android:text="@string/ok"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                style="@style/LightGreenButton"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My Java Code

```
final Dialog itemDialog = new Dialog(QuestionnaireActivity.this);
        itemDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.ZoomOutZoomInDialogAnim);
        itemDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_q6_options);
        itemDialog.setCancelable(true);
        itemDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        //dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.white);
        //dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.transparent_light)));

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int DialogWidth;
        int DialogHeight;

        DialogWidth = (int) (size.x * 0.95);
        DialogHeight = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        itemDialog.getWindow().setLayout(DialogWidth, DialogHeight);
        itemDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        itemDialog.show();
```

Comment: is it a dialog fragment?

Comment: You should consider adding some code, both xml and java. Without any line of what you wrote we can't help that much

Comment: It is a Dialog in Activity class. I posted my code.

Comment: try this : `itemDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);` This will adjust your view when keyboard pops up.

Comment: @AkshayBhat It is not working

Comment: try using AlertDialog

Comment: Not working with AlertDialog also